# Can someone provide a 'map' to measure theory, Hilbert spaces, metric spaces, point-set topology, etc?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

All analysis books (Rudin, Folland, etc.) cover the same material.  But if you are trying to study it on your own,it would be helpful to know (1) what motivated the various developments and (2) how the topics 'fit together'.

The degree of abstraction in some of these areas is quite impressive, but surely they arose from a practical set of problems and someone can draw a diagram of how they are interlinked and what begot what - and what depends on what.

The topics I keep running around in circles on are:
Measure theory, Borel sets, and Lebesgue measure; Normed and metric spaces, $L^p$ spaces, Banach spaces, and Hilbert spaces, and the concept of 'being Hausdorf'; and modes of convergence.

Comment: Baby Rudin and Munkres (simultaneously), then Folland

Comment: Borel sets, measure theory, and Lebesgue integrals form a development sequence.  $L^p$, spaces, Hilbert space are particular Banach spaces, which are normed spaces.  Hausdorf  is a concept of point set topology.  Point set topology, which includes metric spaces is usually taught in parallel to measure theory.  Both are precursors to the Banach space ideas.